# Retrieve the Opportunity Record ID in Flow

Tags: flow

I am trying to create a child record in a Flow off an opportunity. Once the flow is triggered, I'm not finding clear documentation that shows an example of storing then passing the id before creating the record.

Comment: How are you invoking the flow, what parameters and how are you passing them to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable element to your flow. Make sure it is at least an "input" variable type. Then when you call your flow, you call it by passing a parameter of your variable name like /flow/YourFlow?YourVariableName=VariableValue. Then you use that variable in your flow elements to do whatever you want to do.